# PowerShell: do not execute specific code on -Whatif

Tags: powershell

**Is there any way to ignore a line when executing the `-whatif` flag?**

After adding `SupportsShouldProcess` to a command in a .psm1 module, it errors when executing `-whatif` on the target function.

The affected piece of code is basicly trying to determine if $Path has been set and if not, it will check if it can use the given name as a path:

```
function New-pallet {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='Low')]
param([string]Name, [string]Path)
if (!($Path)) {
    if (Test-Path "..\$Name") {
        if ((get-location).Path -eq (Resolve-Path "..\$Name").Path) {
            $Path = "..\$Name"
        } else {
            $Path = ".\$Name"
        }
    } else {
        $Path = ".\$Name"
    }
}
if (!(Test-Path $Path)) {
    New-Item $Path -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}
}
```

Now the issue is that when running what if, it errors on the resolve-Path:

```
C:\Users\some_user> New-Pallet -Name test -whatif
```

The subsequent error:

```
Resolve-Path : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\some_user\test' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\some_user\Projects\some_project.psm1:255 char:72
+ ... MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value (Resolve-Path $Path).Path
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\some_user\Projects\someproject\test:String) [Resolve-Path], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ResolvePathCommand
```

The resolve-path works fine when executed without -whatif

**Is there any way to ignore this line when using the `-whatif` flag?**
**Or a way to check if -whatif is being used?**

Comment: I don't see any `-WhatIf` in your code. Not knowing where `$Name` stems from this might work `if ((Get-Location).Path -eq (Get-Item $Name).Parent.FullName) {`

Comment: Also, unless you explicitly set your working directory somewhere else in your script, using a relative path may not be a good idea.

Comment: It's inside a function. Name is being passed by said function. Updated the question to make this all more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `$pscmdlet.ShouldProcess` is where the magic is at.

more info on it here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.shouldprocess?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0